# Panda, how to shorten/hide a list in a dataframe when using print

Tags: pandas, dataframe, printing

I'm using a dataframe with a lot of relevant data so I can have an easy access to all the relevant information when doing. It looks as such

```
df
     ion    m/n  qte   C1    C2   rCC  compte
0     H   1.00    1  0.1  0.25  0.50       2
1    H2   1.00    3  0.5  0.30  1.00       4
2  10B2   5.00    1  0.6  0.30  0.50       4
3  11B2   5.50    0  0.2  0.20  1.00       0
4   10B  10.00    0  0.2  0.20  1.00       0
5   11B  11.00    0  0.2  0.20  1.00       0
6   Si2  14.01    1  0.8  0.80  1.00       0
7   Fe2  26.90    1  0.8  0.35  0.65       3
8  Fe2*  27.90    1  0.5  0.50  1.00       7
```

Later in the code I add two columns which, for each row, contains a *very* long list.
This makes any print(df) unreadable as it looks like this after adding the new rows.

```
df with fluxC1 and fluxC2 columns 
     ion  ...                                             fluxC2
0     H  ...  [0.0004506072467966082, 0.0004511067891697997,...
1    H2  ...  [9.65067757502627e-05, 9.663517466177602e-05, ...
2  10B2  ...  [9.65067757502627e-05, 9.663517466177602e-05, ...
3  11B2  ...  [0.0021039651287393384, 0.002105830883498985, ...
4   10B  ...  [0.0021039651287393384, 0.002105830883498985, ...
5   11B  ...  [0.0021039651287393384, 0.002105830883498985, ...
6   Si2  ...  [1.9595400763556396e-11, 1.966500053364854e-11...
7   Fe2  ...  [2.0668903644852728e-05, 2.070098966831758e-05...
8  Fe2*  ...  [2.030468908656194e-07, 2.0349733523508614e-07...
```

Is there any way for me to print my df so that the list is show as [...] or something similar so that my printed df would look like this

```
df
         ion    m/n  qte   C1    C2   rCC  compte  fluxC1  fluxC2
    0     H   1.00    1  0.1  0.25  0.50       2   [...]   [...]
    1    H2   1.00    3  0.5  0.30  1.00       4   [...]   [...]
    2  10B2   5.00    1  0.6  0.30  0.50       4   [...]   [...]
    3  11B2   5.50    0  0.2  0.20  1.00       0   [...]   [...]
    4   10B  10.00    0  0.2  0.20  1.00       0   [...]   [...]
    5   11B  11.00    0  0.2  0.20  1.00       0   [...]   [...]
    6   Si2  14.01    1  0.8  0.80  1.00       0   [...]   [...]
    7   Fe2  26.90    1  0.8  0.35  0.65       3   [...]   [...]
    8  Fe2*  27.90    1  0.5  0.50  1.00       7   [...]   [...]
```

I havn't even found a way to print a list as a [...] or with only very few elements in it, like printing a rounded list (without rounding anything in the df) so I'm a bit skeptical.

Answer (score 2):

You can use style formatting offered by Pandas. There are two ways to go about this. One is to use [style.format()](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.io.formats.style.Styler.format.html) on your dataframe (df) on each invocation where you want to display your df.

```
df.style.format({'fluxC1': '[...]', 'fluxC2': '[...]'})
```

You can use whatever style you want for your columns. The syntax to remember is to use a dict where key is column name and value is the style you want, like above. Or, use a callable if you have some complicated logic. Consult documentation for more info on this.

**Another approach** is to set pd options for style formatting so that you no longer have to pass format each time. Here's one way to do that (with a sample dataframe for better understanding):

```
import string
import pandas as pd

# A Style formatter that styles only Lists which are of len > 2
def style_formatter(i):
    if isinstance(i, list):
        if len(i) > 2:
            return '[...]'
        return i
    return i
pd.set_option('styler.format.formatter', style_formatter)

# Sample dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame({'colA': [[*string.ascii_letters] for i in range(0, 6)], 'colB': [i for i in range(0, 6)]})
```

Default `df` output:

```
    colA                                                colB
0   [a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i, j, k, l, m, n, o, ...   0
1   [a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i, j, k, l, m, n, o, ...   1
2   [a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i, j, k, l, m, n, o, ...   2
3   [a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i, j, k, l, m, n, o, ...   3
4   [a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i, j, k, l, m, n, o, ...   4
5   [a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i, j, k, l, m, n, o, ...   5
```

To style output, call df as `df.style`. Example output after auto-styling based on pd styling option:

```
    colA    colB
0   [...]   0
1   [...]   1
2   [...]   2
3   [...]   3
4   [...]   4
5   [...]   5
```

**Serious note**: styling can take a while if you run it on a big  dataframe. Better approach is to get your data and then use styling over it. E.g. `df.head(20).style`

Comment: You can also set the `styler` options for `max_rows` which should reduce any overhead since no processing is then performed on more rows.

Answer (score 0):

This might be able to help you, I use this a lot when working with bigger dataframes

```
pd.set_option('display.max_rows', 500)
pd.set_option('display.max_columns', 500)
pd.set_option('display.width', 1000)
```

Comment: I've already tried max_columns and for some reasons it starts from the end which actually exacerbate my problem.

I basically only see the index and the fluxc2 of my example.

display.width doesn't change anything no matter the value I put in. Could it have anything to do with the consol or the way I print ? I'm working with Spyder.

Thanks for the answer